# How does the retry logic works in kafka producers?

Tags: apache-kafka, producer

How does the retry logic works in producers ?

I checked the producer config documentation related to retry but could not understand clearly?

Please simplify and help me understand. Thanks

Comment: If your records fail to send, it's sent again in another batch. What exactly is hard to understand?

Answer (score -1):

> The Producer config property retries defaults to 0 and is the retry
> count if Producer does not get an ack from Kafka Broker. The Producer
> will only retry if record send fail is deemed a transient error (API).
> The Producer will act as if your producer code resent the record on a
> failed attempt. Note that timeouts are re-tried, but retry.backoff.ms
> (default to 100 ms) is used to wait after failure before retrying the
> request again. If you set retry > 0, then you should also set
> max.in.flight.requests.per.connection to 1, or there is the
> possibility that a re-tried message could be delivered out of order.
> You have to decide if out of order message delivery matters for your
> application.

For more details, refer [here](http://cloudurable.com/blog/kafka-tutorial-kafka-producer-advanced-java-examples/index.html)